# Can't access sqlite db from Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Test")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val data = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
  Map(
    "url" -> "jdbc:sqlite:/nv/pricing/ix_tri_pi.sqlite3",
    "dbtable" -> "SELECT security_id FROM ix_tri_pi")).load()

data.foreach {
  row => println(row.getInt(1))
}
```

And I try to submit it with:

```
spark-submit \
  --class "com.novus.analytics.spark.SparkTest" \ 
  --master "local[4]" \
 /Users/smabie/workspace/analytics/analytics-spark/target/scala-2.10/analytics-spark.jar \
  --conf spark.executer.extraClassPath=sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar \
  --conf  spark.driver.extraClassPath=sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar \
  --driver-class-path sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar \
  --jars sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

I am using Spark version 1.6.1, if that helps.
Thanks!

Comment: Is `/nv/pricing/ix_tri_pi.sqlite3` the absolute path to the DB? Also try defining your jar as the last parameter of `spark-submit`.

Comment: I honestly can't believe this worked. Thanks a bunch. Why on earth isn't `spark_submit` agnostic about the order of command-line arguments? To be frank, this strikes me as absolutely ridiculous...

Comment: "Why on earth isn't spark_submit agnostic about the order of command-line arguments?" That's [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html): options go first, parameters which aren't options after them. In particular, this allows using `--` to separate operands.

Comment: @sturm I posted my question as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining your jar as the last parameter of `spark-submit`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify driver class in options explicitly?

```
options(
  Map(
    "url" -> "jdbc:sqlite:/nv/pricing/ix_tri_pi.sqlite3",
    "driver" -> "org.sqlite.JDBC",
    "dbtable" -> "SELECT security_id FROM ix_tri_pi"))
```

I had similar issue trying to load PostgreSQL table.

Also, possible cause may be in classloading:

> The JDBC driver class must be visible to the primordial class loader
>   on the client session and on all executors. This is because Java’s
>   DriverManager class does a security check that results in it ignoring
>   all drivers not visible to the primordial class loader when one goes
>   to open a connection. One convenient way to do this is to modify
>   compute_classpath.sh on all worker nodes to include your driver JARs.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#troubleshooting